# Override validations of gem devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

In my model user I add the following validations  The problem is that devise have implemented its own validations. How can I override the validations of Devise

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable and :timeoutable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  validates_presence_of :email, :message=>"email no puede estar vacio"
  validates_presence_of :password, :message=>"password no puede estar vacio"
  validates_presence_of :password_confirmation,:message=>"validate confirmation no puede estar vacio"
  end
```

Browser

```
Email can't be blank  #validation of devise
Email email no puede estar vacio #my own validation
Password can't be blank #validation of devise
Password password no puede estar vacio #my own validation
Password confirmation validate confirmation no puede estar vacio
```

Other problem that I have is that rails shows the name of attribute before of the customized message

```
Email email no puede estar vacio #my own validation #wrong
email no puede estar vacio #well
```

Comment: if you are overriding devise validation just to display a message in spanish i think you are doing it wrong. You should rather write a spanish locale file es.yml and translate devise error messages in this file (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n). Set the locale to spanish with I18n.locale = :es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the `:validatable` devise module...

you can customise the following lines in the `confing/initializers/devise.rb`

```
# ==> Configuration for :validatable
# Range for password length.
config.password_length = 8..128

# Email regex used to validate email formats. It simply asserts that
# one (and only one) @ exists in the given string. This is mainly
# to give user feedback and not to assert the e-mail validity.
# config.email_regexp = /\A[^@]+@[^@]+\z/
```

but if you are trying to override the error message (and solve the issue with the field name mentioned before your translation), 
you better remove your validations (in favour of devise ones)

in other words you have to remove these lines

```
validates_presence_of :email, :message=>"email no puede estar vacio"
validates_presence_of :password, :message=>"password no puede estar vacio"
validates_presence_of :password_confirmation,:message=>"validate confirmation no puede estar vacio"
```

and you can override the validation messages using the [Rails I18n API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)
specifically [part 4](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#looking-up-translations)

in simpler words... you have to provide the locale files for your preferred language (`:es`) in the `config/locales/es.rb`
providing those specific translations

```
# please correct me if i'm wrong.
es:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        record_invalid:
          email: email no puede estar vacio
          password: password no puede estar vacio
          password_confirmation: validate confirmation no puede estar vacio
```

but it's highly advisable to have the field that failed validation there.

**note:**
if you are looking for just provide another locale for the devise error messages (say `:es` locales)...

then it's better to copy `config/locales/devise.en.yml` to `config/locales/devise.es.yml` and edit it accordingly...
or use the devise wiki (github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n)

Comment: Thanks artmees , What happened if I have two files .yml   " devise.es.yml" and "es.yml" how the application know which file to use

Comment: Have a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setup-the-rails-application-for-internationalization).. There is no problem.. But I don't know what will happen if you provided the same key multiple times in the same or across multiple files

Comment: It's better to use the devise.es.yml to override devise strings only... But your locale (es.yml) to override your locales... Please invest some time to read the documentation... To know how to customize and follow the convention...